# Most efficient way to load a large buffer into an html element

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have made a custom report viewer control that utilized the output of an ssrs render request. I am having difficulty matching the speed of the ssrs ReportViewer control. The report is 2.5 mb.

I am watching the request and responses over the wire and can see it is taking roughly 2.8 seconds to get the buffer of the contents from ssrs. However, it is taking 10-15 seconds to show the content inside of an html element in my current view.

The problem is when I log into the ssrs manager directly and render the report it takes just as long to process the report however, it only takes, 3 seconds to render in the ssrs report viewer control.

The original design was to place the html as a payload on the ajax response. Then I thought that the json serialization/deserialization could be the bottleneck so I added the ability to save the output to a temp folder on the server as html and call load(html)...no improvement.

I am using the code below to load the content in my page from the `Ajax.BeginForm` success function :

```
function setReportContent(content, isUrl) {
    if(isUrl)
        $('#reportContent').load(content);
    else
        $("#reportContent").html(content);
    showReportWaitIndicator(false);
    $("#reportContent").show();
 }
```

I cant figure out why there is such a huge discrepancy in rendering times between the ssrs report viewer control and the way I am loading.

Is there a more efficient technique to load large content other than  `.load(url);` ?

**Edit:** I have downloaded the html file and opened it directly in the browser and the markup was rendered instantly. Why does appending the contents to the dom take up to 20 seconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution but it uses an IFrame and I am iffy on that but it matches the speed of the ssrs report viewer. In a nutshell loading an IFrame does not contain some of the overhead of placing the contents in the dom. Made a small adjustment to the setip and it works.

```
function setReportContent(content, isUrl, renderInIFrame) {        
    if (isUrl) {
        if (renderInIFrame)
            $("#reportContent").html("<iframe id='reportFrame' scrolling='yes' onload='resizeReportFrame();' src='" + content + "'\></iframe>");
        else
            $("#reportContent").load(content);
    }
    else {
        if (renderInIFrame) {
           $("#reportContent").html("<iframe id='reportFrame' scrolling='yes' onload='resizeReportFrame();'\></iframe>");
           $('#reportFrame').contents().find('html').html(content);
        }
        else
            $("#reportContent").html(content);            
   }
   showReportWaitIndicator(false);
   $("#reportContent").show();
}
```